# how to push the value into array with loop iteration

Tags: angularjs

```
$http.get('v1/item_id/' + item_id + '/user_id/' + auth.getCurrentUser.user_id)
    .success(function(res) {
        var data = res.data;
        var users_children = [];
        var new_data = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i].user_id == auth.getCurrentUser().children[i].user_id) {
                users_children.push({
                    'user_id': data[i].user_id
                });
                users.filter(function(item) {
                    if (item.user_id != users_children[i].user_id) {
                        new_data.push(item);
                        deferred.resolve(new_data);
                    }
                });
                return;
            } else {
                users.children = "Not data found";
                deferred.resolve(users.children);
                return;
                console.log("Does not exist");
            }
        }
    })
```

// What expect it loop through all the data's user_id and check with current user's user_id if it match push to users_children

// but what happening its checking first object of array and match with first child if it matches return otherwise halting execution. Please guide how to fix this.

Comment: why `return;` if you want to continue execution

Comment: doesnot make any different if you remove this

Comment: it won't stop after one execution, that differnece it will make, did you try? any console errors ? remove `return;` from else too

Comment: Error : auth.getCurrentUser(...).children[i] is undefined

Comment: there you go, it;s undefined, how do you expect to run the code further

Comment: It return me for all the times for last iteration it return me undefined any idea

Comment: for that you have to add code for `auth.getCurrentUser()` I don't know what is this

Comment: auth.getCurrentUser() return me users there are three users when looping it shows me three users in console for forth it says undefined why it run till forth

Comment: because here `auth.getCurrentUser().children[i].user_id` i depends on length of data, and data can be more than users, that's why

Comment: again question same when they meet the exact user_id why it does not call within if condition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164671/discussion-between-alax-and-rakeschand).

Answer (score 0):

I will try to make changes in your code, what i understood from comments

```
$http.get('v1/item_id/' + item_id + '/user_id/' + auth.getCurrentUser.user_id)
    .success(function(res) {
        var data = res.data;
        var users_children = [];
        var new_data = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i].user_id == $scope.isUser(data[i].user_id)) {
                users_children.push({
                    'user_id': data[i].user_id
                });
                users.filter(function(item) {
                    if (item.user_id != users_children[i].user_id) {
                        new_data.push(item);
                        deferred.resolve(new_data);
                    }
                });
                return;
            } else {
                users.children = "Not data found";
                deferred.resolve(users.children);
                return;
                console.log("Does not exist");
            }
        }
    })
```

Create a separate method to check if user_id exist in userlist somewhere

```
$scope.isUser = function(user_id) {
    var user_ids = auth.getCurrentUser().children.map(function(x){
        return x.user_id;
    });
    return (user_ids.indexOf(user_id) !== -1)
}
```

Comment: Does not work but i have a clue

data => Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

user => Array [ Object, Object, Object] 

Within these object we have user_id do we need nested loop..? If yes pls guide Rakesh